# iOS 11 issues with navigationBar prefersLargeTitles

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchcontroller, ios11

**Xcode 9 beta 6 iOS 11**

I have a storyboard for a `viewController`, the **background ImageView**, **tableView** and the **searchFooter view** are the subViews of the view.The structure is as follows:

[image]

In the `AppDelegate` class,I set
`UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true`

and

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(),for: .default)

UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

In the `viewController`class,I set  `navigationItem.searchController = searchController` and `navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true`

> When I run the application, I found that the `shadowImage` of the
>   `navigationBar` was still exist. 
>   The navigationBar wouldn't become normal(not the prefersLargeTitles
>   mode ) automatically(the left gif) when I scrolled the tableView.I hope the navigationBar can work just like the system
>   app(the right gif).

[image: my app][image: system app]

> **A weird behavior:** When I remove the background `imageView`, it can work as well as
>   the system app on the simulator.

I don't know why it happened,I wonder how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: That looks like an iOS/UIKit bug, try reporting it to Apple.

Comment: I just found that the tableview has to be the first subview in the view hierarchy. Still try to see if there is a way to work around.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a small application for your issue. You can reach the project on Github.

[Transparent NavigationBar for iOS11](https://github.com/yillars/transparent-navigation-bar-ios11)

Note: You must use a color for UINavigationBar when scrolling up.

Comment: I'm the original author of this question, this's my new ID.I downloaded the project you provided, it indeed can fix the issue.But one question, why must use a color for UINavigationBar when scrolling up?Any apple docs mention this?Thanks.

Comment: I took a look at the code in your project,you set the `tableView.backgroudView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "main_background"))`.Actually ,the situation isn't the same.I used a UIImageView under the tableView instead of setting a `backgroudView`.You can download my project with the [link](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1kWFhnEJ)

Answer (score 0):

The account has been deleted by `Stack overflow` team. So I use my another ID to comment here. 
I have reported the issue to Apple，they asked me to provide a project and I did, but no more further comment from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Make your TableView Top constraint right under NavigationController's NavigationsBar, not ViewControllers Top. It should work

Answer (score -1):

You should add below line in viewDidLoad()

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

OR YOU CAN implement `viewForHeaderInSection` method of `UITableViewDataSource`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? 
    {
            let search = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            search.searchResultsUpdater = self
            return search.searchBar
    }
```

[Link to see the screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qruOX.png) [Link to see the screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOUl9.png)